# how i can set SPACE between icon and title of Toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm trying to change icon of `Toolbar` when i select `item` , already do this and works fin but title and icon Close together like this picture . i want to set space between them , any idea please ?

[image]

```
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.Fragment_art) {
        final String art = "<font color='#ffd159'>Art</font>";
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.art);
        setTitle(Html.fromHtml(" Wallpapers : "+art));
    } else if (id == R.id.Fragment_Material) {
        final String Material = "<font color='#4acfd9'>Material</font>";
        setTitle(Html.fromHtml(" Wallpapers : "+Material));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.material);

    } else if (id == R.id.Fragment_Natural) {
        final String Natural = "<font color='#49a010'>Natural</font>";
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.natural);
        setTitle(Html.fromHtml(" Wallpapers : "+Natural));
    } else if (id == R.id.Fragment_Animal) {
        final String Animal = "<font color='#e76541'>Animal</font>";
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.animal);
        setTitle(Html.fromHtml("Wallpapers : "+Animal));
        }
```

Comment: A trick like: `"   Wallpapaers"`. :)

Comment: i already tried this but doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

`setTitle(Html.fromHtml("&nbsp;Wallpapers : "+art);`